# Конвертировать Unixtimestamp в Date

Tags: java, android, дата, unixtimestamp

ВКонтакте API возвращает время в Unixtimestamp, я пробую переобразовать их в дату, но мне показывает что сообщения вообще пришло в час ночи, то есть переводит не правильно.

Пример

```
new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss").format(new Date(1432877865))
```

Возвращает 17:00:17

Это не правильно, потому что время такое 08:37:45

Ладно бы были проблемы с часовым поясом, так оно мне минуты не верно показывает. Пробовал так

```
new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm:ss").format(new Date(1432877865 * 1000))
```

но все равно время не верное. Как правильно его перевести?

Comment: Аналогичный вопрос на английском SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18122608/552014

Comment: вот здесь ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17432735/convert-unix-time-stamp-to-date-in-java ) используют в качестве множителя не `1000`, а `1000L` (или явное приведение к типу `long`). может быть, в этом суть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unixtimestamp в Java передается в миллисекундах. Как несложно догадаться, в миллисекундах много времени не сохранишь, если пользоваться стандартным 4-байтным интом, поэтому нужно использовать long тип:

```
timeLong = timeInt * 1000L;
// или так:
timeLong = (long)timeInt * 1000;
```

То есть Ваш код должен выглядеть так:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date(1432877865 * 1000L))
// или так:
new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss").format(new Date((long)1432877865 * 1000))
```

Не знаю, специально или нет Вы используете kk для указания часов, но на всякий случай указал именно HH (формат от 0 до 23)